# Is this sentence correct: "He devised the article in such a way that each reader understand what he wanted."

Tags: subjunctives

This is about a misleading text, written 100 years ago, that can be interpreted in various ways. It was written to please everybody.

> W. Thompson devised his article in such a way **that each reader understand** what he or she wanted.

Is the above sentence correct? If not what is the right form of it?

The problem is that W. Thomson just tried to fool his readers. We do not know if they fell in his trap. If I use "understood", it means that his trick succeed and each reader understood what he wanted and all were happy. What is an idiomatic way to express that readers may be fooled in the present even though the article was written a long time ago?

Comment: Use *understood* instead of *understand* there and it will work.

Comment: The problem is that W. Thomson just tried to fool his readers. We do not know if they fell in his trap. If I use "understood" it means that his trick succeed and each reader understood what he wanted and all were happy.

Comment: @Robert Werner: If you want to explicitly convey that the devising was in the past, but the understanding is in the present/future, you could use ***understands/will understand***. But your ***understand*** could never be valid, because it combines a singular subject *(each reader)* with a plural verb form. You'd also need to deal with the incorrect mixing of present/future and past tense *wanted*.

Comment: @Fumble - I was thinking that ***could understand*** could also work.

Comment: ... note that feasibly your cited usage is a non-idiomatic / dated / archaic "subjunctive" usage.

Comment: It can be a subjunctive.

Comment: If you *know* that, you know better than me, and I'm a native speaker with a degree in English. So why would you need to ask your question on a learner's site?

Comment: What I need is the correct, idiomatic, modern, etc. form of the sentence marked in yellow but I want its exact meaning unchanged. I do not suggest anything.

Comment: In an attempt to find more "context", I've just searched Google for the text string [*"**devised his article in such a way**"*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZQC_WKPEJKSK8Qf1l7CAAg#q=%22devised+his+article+in+such+a+way%22&*). It produced just a single result, followed by the non-contentious *...such a way that choir directors **can obtain** some insight into the treatment of the voice.* Your version just doesn't look credible to me, and I don't think it's meaningful to suggest that it's in some way "tenseless" with respect to whether the understanding is past, present, or future.

Comment: The question is not asking for proofreading. The questioner is not a troll, though he may be as pissed off as (a mythical) one. This is a perfectly legitimate question from a (German speaking?) learner about how to cast his sentence in something like the subjunctive.

Comment: I have deleted a number of comments here. [Be Nice](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) and if you find someone else is not being nice, flag it for moderator attention instead of handing it back to them with interest. Calling people trolls/accusing them of running sock puppets is not acceptable behavior.

Comment: @ColleenV - Another appropriate response would be to address the concerns of the critics by editing the question.

Comment: @J.R Yes, I included that in my edit comment, and it also merits repeating it here in the comments. Discussion in comments should have improving the question as its main goal. If someone doesn't understand your question, don't assume all of the fault lies with the reader. I think most of the best questions on ELL have been edited at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convey the subjunctive meaning we can use a periphrastic construction with modal **might**:

... so that each reader might glean | understand | find | take away ....

Comment: I will use "might" as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine.  The verb "understand" is in the present subjunctive there.  It's a little formal that it's even causing native speakers on here to question it.  English has modals to replace subjunctive forms like the one you have above, which is either very formal or archaic in how you've written it, but by no means incorrect.  I liked it.  It sounded Shakespearean.  I've said it that way before as well when I have wanted to sound very formal or intelligent!